# Why does $\int\limits_0^\infty {\ln(x) \over x}\ dx$ diverge?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Why does $\int\limits_0^\infty {\ln(x) \over x}\ dx$ diverge?

I know it diverges from $1 \to \infty$, however how can I prove that the $-\infty$ from $0 \to 1$ is smaller than the area from $1 \to \infty$.

Comment: What does it mean to converge if $\int_1^\infty$ diverges?

Comment: integral from 0 to 1 would have to be exactly the same?

Comment: In order to prove that such integral is divergent it is enough to notice that $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{x}\,dx=+\infty$. In a way, the divergent contribution over $(0,1)$ compensates the divergent contribution over $(1,+\infty)$. The substitution $x=e^t$ formally converts the original integral into $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}t\,dt$, which is not convergent, but with a principal value equal to $0$.

Comment: What is your definition of the integral converging? If you can't say that, the problem is meaningless.

Comment: @MaxKempar Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

This integral diverges in the regular improper Riemann sense, since it is defined as 
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_\epsilon^1\frac{\ln x}{x}\mathrm dx+\lim_{M\to \infty}\int_1^M\frac{\ln x}{x}\mathrm dx
$$
the latter of which diverges.

Perhaps you are talking about the principal value integral? In which case we can indeed make sense of this integral using Cauchy principal value, in which case it is defined as
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^{1/\epsilon}\frac{\ln x}{x}\mathrm dx
$$
and we can substitue $u=\ln x$ to find equality with
$$
\int_{\ln(1/\epsilon)}^{\ln \epsilon} u\mathrm du=\frac12\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}([\ln(\epsilon)]^2-[\ln(1/\epsilon)]^2)\\
=\frac12\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}(\ln(\epsilon)-\ln(1/\epsilon))(\ln(\epsilon)+\ln(1/\epsilon)\\
=0\cdot\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\ln(\epsilon)=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Between $0$ and $1$, set $x=\dfrac1t$, $\;\mathrm d x=-\dfrac {\mathrm dt}{t^2}$. You obtain
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x}\,\mathrm d x=\int_\infty^1-t\ln t\cdot-\frac {\mathrm dt}{t^2}=-\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln t}{t}\,\mathrm d t,$$
hence it also diverges.

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that the integral from 1 to inf has the same magnitude as the integral from 0 to 1, thus the overall integral is 0?

Comment: @MaxKempar please see the definition in my answer: you allow the upper and lower limits to go at different speed in the regular riemann improper integral

Comment: The definition of a convergent integral, when it is a improper integral on both sides, is that *each* integral is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Notice 
$$\int^1_0\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx=-\int^{\infty}_1\frac{\ln y}{y}\,dy$$
after change of variable $x:=1/y$. Therefore
$$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx=\int^{\infty}_1\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx+\int^1_0\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx=\int^{\infty}_1\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx-\int^{\infty}_1\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx=+\infty-\infty$$
This is an undetermined form. Hence if you want to make sense somehow of your integral you can consider the following integral for a given $a>1$:
$$\int^{a}_{1/a}\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx$$
and then let $a\uparrow+\infty$. In this case you would get:
$$\lim_{a\to+\infty}\int^{a}_{1/a}\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx=\lim_{a\to+\infty}\Big(\int^{a}_1\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx-\int^{a}_1\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx\Big)=\lim_{a\to+\infty}0=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The improper integral

$$-\int\limits_0^1 {\ln(x) \over x}\ dx$$

diverges by limit comparison with

$$\int\limits_0^1 {1 \over x}\ dx$$